Java swing InvokeLater doesn't repaint immediately
I am working on a game. When trying to visualize using a game-loop in a "main"-Thread the paintComponent method is only called scarcely. I've read up on many other similar problems, but none seem to help me. Could be, that I still don't understand everything correctly.
I know it is still an issue with the EDT as when I move my mouse or press a key the game is rendered smoothly.
Thank you!
Here my shortened code:
public class Game implements Runnable {
    
    private GamePanel  gamePanel;
    private Thread gameThread;
    private final int FPS_SET = 120;

    
    public Game() {
        gamePanel  = new GamePanel();
        gamePanel.requestFocus();
        
        gameThread = new Thread(this);
        gameThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        
        double timePerFrame = 1000000000.0 / FPS_SET ; 
        long lastFrame = System.nanoTime();
        long now       = lastFrame;
        
        
        while(true) {
            
            now = System.nanoTime();
            if (now - lastFrame >= timePerFrame) {
                // Updates Scenery
                _reDraw();
                lastFrame = now;
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    private void _reDraw() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                gamePanel.repaint();
            }
        });
    }
    
}

public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
    // ...
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // draw
    }
}


You probably should call gamePanel.getToolkit().sync() right after calling repaint().

Yes! That works. But what does it do?

The documentation in the link pretty much says it all.  It flushes any buffered (off-screen) graphics changes so they are forced to appear.  Such buffering can be complex and can be system dependent, so it may not always seem to be needed, but for animation in custom painting, it should always be used, to guarantee things work everywhere.

Surprises me I didn't find any mention of it in all the other posts I've looked though. In any case, thank you!

This question is similar to: Why does my custom Swing component repaint faster when I move the mouse?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hey thanks for your request. How do I edit it in a way to make that clear? I think my question is well stated for the answer I was looking for (and got). I looked for 2 hours trying to find a solution and did not come across the mentioned post. And it does not have the solution I got here (which works and is explained). I am fairly "new" to Overflow, I'm not sure what the right move is. If you think it should be edited or something similar please let me know how. :)

You shouldn't be using a while (true) loop as your GUI event loop. Much better options are available.

Hey :), could you refer me some? This is only the shortened code (so the graphics update is only one part of the loop, it also includes all other computations), but would you recommend to put it in a different loop/Thread?

Use Swing’s Timer and since it is performing the action inside the event handling thread, you can call paintImmediately in its action. While the timer is active, in other words, you know that you’re painting repeatedly you may set IgnoreRepaint to true

This answer will not tell you how to solve your problem as @VGR already told you the way to go. This is a tentative explanation on the problem you faced.
From repaint() doc:

If this component is a lightweight component, this method causes a
call to this component's paint method as soon as possible. Otherwise,
this method causes a call to this component's update method as soon as
possible.

As soon as possible do not mean that each time you call repaint() paint will be called. You may call repaint() faster than the toolkit is able to answer your request.
From the doc again:

App-triggered Painting
In an application-triggered painting operation, the component decides
it needs to update its contents because its internal state has
changed. (For example,. a button detects that a mouse button has been
pressed and determines that it needs to paint a "depressed" button
visual).

and :

The Paint Method
Regardless of how a paint request is triggered, the AWT uses a
"callback" mechanism for painting, and this mechanism is the same for
both heavyweight and lightweight components. This means that a program
should place the component's rendering code inside a particular
overridden method, and the toolkit will invoke this method when it's
time to paint.

the toolkit will invoke this method when it's time to paint is the important part.
and:

App-triggered painting
An app-triggered painting operation takes place as follows:
The program determines that either part or all of a component needs to
be repainted in response to some internal state change.
The program invokes repaint() on the component, which registers an
asynchronous request to the AWT that this component needs to be
repainted.
The AWT causes the event dispatching thread to invoke update() on the
component.
NOTE: If multiple calls to repaint() occur on a component before the
initial repaint request is processed, the multiple requests may be
collapsed into a single call to update(). The algorithm for
determining when multiple requests should be collapsed is
implementation-dependent. If multiple requests are collapsed, the
resulting update rectangle will be equal to the union of the
rectangles contained in the collapsed requests.

Real painting is not on your side, it's on the host UI
side. There may be many events that do not permit the painting to take
place (your window is not visible, there is more urgent things to do,
etc).
At least, we known that for a repaint there will be a paint in the
future, but several repaint may lead to a single paint.
Note: there is no need to trigger repaint on the ui-thread (via invokeLater). You just have to call it directly from your thread as it pushes the request to later paint on the ui-thread. Prefer:
private void _reDraw() {
    gamePanel.repaint();
}

